# Snowflake snowpark Python Interpreter Error: NamError: name is not defined

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm executing a function in Python/Snowpark and I'm getting the error:
[image]

I appreciate this is a Python beginners error, however I'm not sure why I'm getting the error: `NameError: name 'conn' is not defined` when I have defined conn in the function:

```
conn = connection.connect(connectionProperties, log)
```

Again, this is an error that I should know how to fix, but I don't.

The fulll code is as follows:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

import wheel_loader

def getStruct(conn): 
    wheel_loader.load('whlib-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl')
    
    from whlib.utils import connectionProperties as connProps
    from whlib.utils import connection as connection
    from whlib.utils import whliblogging as log
    from whlib.cln import entity as entity
    
    dbConnectionProperties = connProps.DbConnectionProperties()
    dbConnectionProperties.DBServer = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    dbConnectionProperties.DBUser = 'xxxxxxx'
    dbConnectionProperties.DBPword = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    dbConnectionProperties.DBDatabase = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    
    connectionProperties = connProps.ConnectionProperties()
    connectionProperties.dbConnectionProperties = dbConnectionProperties
    

    log = logs.Logging(connectionProperties)
    conn = connection.connect(connectionProperties, log)
    
    
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return getStruct(conn)
```

Any thoughts

Comment: You are defining `conn` inside a function that is expecting that as an input.  Either define it outside the function and pass it in, or don't pass anything into the function and just return what you need from `getStruct`.

Comment: @MikeWalton, thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately, ```conn``` is passed in from a module, so it needs to be passed inside the function

Comment: When you call the function `getStruct` you pass `conn` in the `main` function, but that `conn` is not defined anywhere in the main function, so you get the error. The error is not about the `conn` you define inside the function but the one you pass in the main.